# Error on Jquery on webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-applications

In my webpage I have two controls that are bind to jquery.
One is a button to copy the Textbox value to clipboard and other is textbox to enter date.

[image]

But the problem is when I debug this web application, it throws the jquery error.
And when I comment out one javascript method and debug, it works (tried with both javascript method).

But when I dont't comment out, it doesn't work.

[image]

Aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="searchSerialResult.aspx.cs" Inherits="Locker.searchSerialResult" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">

        .auto-style3 {
            color: #CC3300;
            font-size: x-large;
        }
        .auto-style1 {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: large;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            color: #000000;
        }
        </style>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


    <p>
        &nbsp;<p>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong> <span class="auto-style3">&nbsp; Recorded Information</span><span class="auto-style1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
     <div style="width:70%; margin: auto auto; text-align:left; ">
         <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None">
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style2" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large" Text="Details for :"></asp:Label>
             &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large; color: #0000FF"></asp:Label>
             <br />
             <br />
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style2" Font-Bold="False" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large" Text="Serial :"></asp:Label>
             &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid"  Enabled="False" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Width="213px"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Copy Me!"/>

                    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <script src="Scripts/jquery.zclip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <script src="Scripts/jquery.zclip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
                    <script>

                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $('#<%=Button3.ClientID%>').zclip({
                                path: 'ZeroClipboard.swf',
                                copy: function () { return $('#<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').val(); }
                        });
                        });
                 </script>
             <br />
             <br />
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style2" Font-Bold="False" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large" Text="Serial Type :"></asp:Label>
             &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="26px" Width="181px" AutoPostBack="True" Enabled="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                 <asp:ListItem>Never Expire</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>Expire</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style2" Font-Bold="False" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large" Text="Expiry Date :" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
             &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Enabled="False" Height="16px" Visible="False" Width="136px"></asp:TextBox>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;

             <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
             <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
             <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
             <script>
                $(function () {
                $("#<%=TextBox6.ClientID%>").datepicker({

                });
            });
        </script>&nbsp;<br />
             <br />
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large" Text="Description :" CssClass="auto-style2"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="Medium" Height="48px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="217px" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
             <br />
             <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: small" Text="Last Editor was " CssClass="auto-style2"></asp:Label>
             <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: small" CssClass="auto-style2"></asp:Label>
             <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Edit" Width="97px" />
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Update" Visible="False" Width="97px" />
             <br />
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <br />
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large; color: #0000FF" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
             <br />
             <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</asp:Content
```

Works if i comment out anyone of the javascript method..

Comment: *side note*: There are much, much better ways to align elements on a page than using `&nbsp;`. That's just lazy. :/ You should learn CSS or work with someone who knows it.

Answer (score 0):

You're including more than one version of jQuery, and the second version overwrites the first version.

Therefore any plugins associated with the first version are removed. (ZClip in this case)

Answer (score 0):

That´s right. You can´t use the same jquery plugin library (zclip) twice in order to append it to the $ sign. If you really need both (source and minified) you should use a different variable name for one of them. Otherwise it would cause conflicts.

So, I rather you to use this code:

```
            <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/jquery.zclip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#<%=Button3.ClientID%>').zclip({
                        path: 'ZeroClipboard.swf',
                        copy: function () { return $('#<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').val(); }
                });
                });
             </script>
```

If you are on production environment. If you are on development environment, then you should use the uncompressed version file of the jQuery plugin.

Comment: then you should check if the zclip plugin is compatible with your jquery version. If you only have included this two js libraries, it should work.

Comment: It works with with no problem even with both jquery but if you look at my code there is another control that uses jquery as well. Exception throws if I comment out that jquery..